# Show the output (echo) of a php file on my html site

Tags: php, html, echo

So my problem is the following:

I have this php file which I use for a contact form:

```
<?php
/* [VERIFY CAPTCHA FIRST] */
$secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
$verify = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));

/* [PROCESS YOUR FORM] */
if ($verify->success) {
  $to = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
  $subject = "Kontakt Website";
  $message = "Name - " . $_POST['name']; 
  $message .= "\nEmail - " . $_POST['email'];
  $message .= "\Message - " . $_POST['message'];
  if (@mail($to, $subject, $message)) {
    echo "Message sent!";
  } else {
    echo "Nachricht konnte nicht gesendet werden!";
  }
} else {
    header("Location: index.html#contactline");
    echo "Invalid captcha";
    exit;
}
?>
```

And then here is the form inside of my index.html:

```
<section>
    <form method="post" action="contact.php">
        <div class="row gtr-50">
            <div class="col-6 col-12-small">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="contact-name" placeholder="Name" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-12-small">
                <input type="text" name="email" id="contact-email" placeholder="E-Mail" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
                <textarea name="message" id="contact-message" placeholder="Nachricht" rows="4"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxxxxxxxxxxx" data-theme="dark"></div>
            <div class="col-12_Submit">
                <ul class="actions">
                    <li><input type="submit" class="style1" value="Senden" /></li>
                    <li><input type="reset" class="style2" value="Zurücksetzen" /></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="status"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</section>
```

So my question is is it possible to obtain the echo of the php file like "Message sent" or "Invalid Captcha" and display it on my index.html for example under the contact form as text in the `<div class="status"></div>` after I hit the submit button?

And If yes - how can I do it?

Comment: `So my question is is it possible to obtain the echo of the ph....` Yes, it's possible

Comment: I think it's possible by using ajax, since the form is html not php

Comment: You should use local storage concept of javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I get the question right, why not make the file a php file instead of a html document since php file can output html. So your index.html should be index.php and then include your php script for the mail, also create an empty variable for message in the script and give it a value at every condition. But don't echo it yet, the echoing should be done at the html page.

```
$msg="";
if(@mail($to, $subject, $message){
$msg=="message has been sent";
}
else{
$msg="not sent"; 
}
```

Then in your html div which you want the text to be displayed do this

```
<?php
include "messages_script.php;
?>
<section>
<form method="post" action="contact.php">
<div class="row gtr-50">
<div class="col-6 col-12-small">
<input type="text" name="name" id="contact-name" placeholder="Name" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-12-small">
            <input type="text" name="email" id="contact-email" placeholder="E-Mail" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <textarea name="message" id="contact-message" placeholder="Nachricht" rows="4"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxxxxxxxxxxx" data-theme="dark"></div>
        <div class="col-12_Submit">
            <ul class="actions">
                <li><input type="submit" class="style1" value="Senden" /></li>
                <li><input type="reset" class="style2" value="Zurücksetzen" /></li>
            </ul>
 <?php echo $msg; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="status"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Set your message in a variable for example $message then by rendering **index.php** check a simple if condition

```
<div class="status"><? if(isset($message)) echo $message?></div>
```

and if you want to use header and send value you could use $_GET[] in index.php